# How do I set up ssh agent forwarding for git under a different username?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

I frequently need to ssh into boxes under a different username. I would like to be able to clone git repositories as that other user, using my ssh keys. For example,

```
ssh me@box 'git clone git@server:org/repo.git'
```

works, but

```
ssh other@box 'git clone git@server:org/repo.git'
```

does not, even if I have ssh-agent forwarding set up (I get the "Permission denied (publickey)" error typical for users who try to clone a git repo but don't have permissions. Changing my global git `user.name` and `user.email` doesn't seem to help.

I ensured that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` exists and is valid in my environment (ssh-agent is running), that `ssh-agent -L` prints the correct keys, and that the clone works under my own username (`me` in the above examples).

My `.ssh/config` looks like

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes
```

It only fails when I try to clone under the `other` user, even with key forwarding enabled, but it works when I clone as `me`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` only apply to commit metadata; they have nothing to do with SSH authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try first:

```
ssh other@box 'ssh -Tv git@server'
```

You will see what SSH key is actually tried and sent to `git@server` from `box`, when logged as `other` through that tunnel.

I would recommend making a dedicated key in `other@box:/home/other/.ssh` and register that public key to the Git repository hosting server under the right account (the account which has the right to clone the `repo.git`).